# Only roles that are Admins can have access to /admin. But its not working

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-6

User.php:

```
public function IsAdmin(){
    return $this->role=='admin';
}
```

Checkifadmin.php (middleware):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if (auth()->user()->role=='admin') {
    return redirect(route('home'));
  }
  return $next($request);
}
```

Kernel.php :

In protected routes

```
'checkifadmin' =>\App\Http\Middleware\Checkifadmin::class,
```

create_users_table.php

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('role')->default('customer');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('admin',function(){
return view('layouts.admin');
})->middleware(['checkifadmin']);
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
})->name('home');
Route::get('/shop/product', function () {
    return view('shop.product');
})->name('shop.product');
Route::get('/shop/shoppingcard', function () {
    return view('shop.shoppingcard');
})->name('shop.shoppingcard');
Route::get('/shop/checkout', function () {
    return view('shop.checkout');
})->name('shop.checkout');

Auth::routes();
```

I have 2 roles in my user. Customer and admin, only admins should have access to /admin but it does not seem to work for some reason. I have copy and pasted every possible code that i have made regarding to this matter, thank u in advance

Comment: if else condition seems wrong. If `admin` let the request proceed and if `customer` redirect to home.

Comment: can u please can it more clear by writing the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware should be like follow if only `admin` are allowed in

Checkifadmin.php (middleware):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()->role !='admin') {
        return redirect(route('home'));
    }

    return $next($request);

}
```

Then you can keep your route as is

```
Route::get('admin',function() {
    return view('layouts.admin');
})->middleware(['checkifadmin']);
```

Comment: still giving the same error mate! 127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times. and the page keeps on loading and loading

Comment: Show me your full route file or check if `home` route is accessible by everyone without login